# Ubuntu 23.04 ignoring Nvidia (535) driver after system updated mesa pkgs

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 23.04, mesa

Running 23.04 with Nvidia RTX 2070 Super and proprietary Nvidia driver 535.Yesterday (july 13 2023) I ran an apt update/upgrade and got a nice chunk of mesa updates. This has left the system ignoring the Nvidia driver - now in software rendering mode.
Card is working, driver 535 is installed and visible with GUI software & updates app but `nvidia-smi` returns  `...couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver`

Seems lately that any update in the graphics stack causes issues. (last time solved with nvidia driver version change)

tried:

- dropping to 525 driver *and* reinstall dkms-525
- back to 535 and reinstall dkms-535

A solemn prayer to the linux graphics Gods.

Comment: I am having similar issues.  I have tried apt remove nvidia-driver-535, reboot, apt install nivida-driver-535.  That has not helped.  I was here looking for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same for me. Solved, apparently, disabling secure boot in system bios.
Don't know why/how this happened.
It's very strange. First time I encountered a problem like this.

Comment: I didn't disable secure boot but my ASUS Bios had a choice of windows or other OS secure boot, I changed to other, solved problem. Thanks for the hint. I dont know boot setup well enough to know how a mesa pkg update would affect boot up.

Comment: I don't know a lot too about secure boot. Just read somewhere that someone resolved that way a similar problem and just tried.
It worked and that's enough for me at the moment.
Anyway, it's strange, something must have happened with some of the latest update to cause an issue like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after last general Ubuntu update. My scree resolution switched back to generic/standard (rather than my selected screen resolution for the monitor which was much higher). The system said it was using 535 but like you, I also when investigating the error log the Nvidia driver was not loaded and the system could not communicate with Nvidia driver.
Clicking on the Nvidia app in the panel also informed me it was not running.

My solution (before switching to full CLI reloads of the Nvidia driver) worked and was as follows:
(I of course could still see my screen)
I used the GUI for 'Additional Drivers' (tab) in the Software Settings app to reset my driver.
(1)I first reset it to the standard Nouveau driver and then reboot.
(2) I then checked the Nouveau driver was selected in Software Settings - additional Driver
(3) I then selected the original Nvidia 535 driver (that I had been running) got it to reload and everything seemed fine once again.
(4) I rebooted the machine just to be sure and since then things are back to normal.

I think this process "under the hood" reran the install of the driver and adjusted any settings/headers etc. to their correct value.

This worked for me. But everyone else may have a different experience.