# External display not detected

Tags: nvidia, 23.04

I have a Lenovo Legion 5i Pro (570 series) with dual boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu 23.04.

Recently (I don't know the reason for this problem), my external monitor connected via HDMI is no longer detected.

What I've tried:

- using the DisplayPort, but it's no longer detected either.
- reinstalling the nvidia drivers several times, either via the "Additional drivers" tab of the Settings app, via the ubuntu-drivers tool or even via the installer downloaded from the Nvidia site.
- several nvidia drivers versions of the driver, namely 470, 510, 525 and 535.

Note:

- I can no longer select a PRIME profile (the tab no longer exists in nvidia-settings).
- I have secure boot enabled, which I need to keep activated.
- I'm using Wayland

Outputs:

lspci:
https://pastebin.com/FH4LBMBp

nvidia-smi:
`NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.`

EDIT: Seems to be similar to [Ubuntu 23.04 ignoring Nvidia (535) driver after system updated mesa pkgs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477851/ubuntu-23-04-ignoring-nvidia-535-driver-after-system-updated-mesa-pkgs), but solution isn't working for me since I need secure boot to be enabled.